Live Activities started but aren't visible
So basically when running the my application on my physical device (iPhone 15 Pro Max) or on iPhone 16 pro on the simulator, when I start a Live Activity it is kind of in the dynamic island. When clicked it opens my app and expands when held but without any content.
empty dynamic island
My app contains 3 targets, the iOS App, Widget Extensions and a Shared framework to distribute models, utility functions and components.
Following Things are true:

App has Notification permission
App has required Live Activities permissions
App has push notification sign in & capabilities
App has no errors

I have tried the following:

Making content more static
logging Activity presence

What I expect:

Visible UI for both Dynamic Island and Lock Screen

here is my code:
Main iOS Application
import ActivityKit
import SwiftUI
import SharedDripe

class LiveActivityManager {
    static let shared = LiveActivityManager()
    private var tripActivity: Activity<TripSummaryAttributes>?
    
    func startTripActivity(trip: Trip, unitSystem: User.UnitSystem) async {
        guard ActivityAuthorizationInfo().areActivitiesEnabled else {
            print("❌ Live Activities not supported on this device")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let initialState = TripSummaryAttributes.ContentState(
                trip: trip,
                unitSystem: unitSystem
            )
            
            let content = ActivityContent(
                state: initialState,
                staleDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: Date())
            )
            
            let activity = try Activity<TripSummaryAttributes>.request(
                attributes: TripSummaryAttributes(),
                content: content,
                pushType: nil
            )
            
            tripActivity = activity
            print("✅ Live Activity started successfully")
            print("Activity ID: \(activity.id)")
            print("Activity state: \(activity.activityState)")
            
        } catch {
            print("❌ Error starting Live Activity: \(error)")
            print("Error details: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func endTripActivity() async {
        await endAllActivities()
        tripActivity = nil
    }
    
    func endAllActivities() async {
        print("Ending all live activities...")
        for activity in Activity<TripSummaryAttributes>.activities {
            await activity.end(nil, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
            print("Ended activity with ID: \(activity.id)")
        }
    }
}

How I call the Live Activity (toggled by a button)
      await LiveActivityManager.shared.startTripActivity(trip: currentTrip, unitSystem: unitSystem)

Widget Extension
//
//  DripeAcitiviesWidget.swift
//  Dripe
//
//  Created by Noah Onyejese on 14.12.24.
//

import ActivityKit
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit
import SharedDripe

struct LiveActiveTripView: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: TripSummaryAttributes.self) { context in
            // Lock screen view
            ZStack {
                Color.blue // Background
                Text("ACTIVE TRIP TEST")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
            }
        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            DynamicIsland {
                // Expanded
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.center) {
                    Text("TEST EXPANDED")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            } compactLeading: {
                // Leading compact
                Text("")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            } compactTrailing: {
                // Trailing compact
                Text("TEST")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            } minimal: {
                // Minimal
                Text("")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}


@main
struct DripeWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        LiveActiveTripView()
    }
}

Shared Framework

public struct TripSummaryAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        public var trip: Trip
        public var unitSystem: User.UnitSystem
        
        public init(trip: Trip, unitSystem: User.UnitSystem) {
            self.trip = trip
            self.unitSystem = unitSystem
        }
    }
    
    public init() {}
}

Thanks in advance!
